# Variable selection / identification of genuine effects in a large-dimensional VAR model

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, high-dimensional

There are 100 commodities that I am tracking. As I attempt to improve my time series models, VAR and VARMA look like they might provide some improved predictions. All of the literature I find on creating VAR models assume that the modeler has some assumption of which items might correlate. Are there methods/practices in finding the related items systematically without prior knowledge of the commodities?

Toolset (Python): Working with pandas, statsmodels and matplotlib mostly.

Comment: Since you have a large number of time series, you may consider using regularization techniques to lessen the sensitivity and decrease the estimation variance of your model. Bayesian VAR modelling could be relevant.

Comment: Have you considered a dynamic factor model?

Comment: Hadn't considered either of those approaches; I'll read up on both (always appreciate links if you know of any papers/articles/examples that explain this clearer than others)

Comment: You could also try GVAR modelling, a summary of this method (essentially hierarchical VAR-modelling) is given in the survey paper of Chudik & Pesaran named 'Theory and Practice of GVAR modelling'